# "good" way to redirect users and robots for internationalization?

Tags: search-engines, redirects, url, internationalization, clean-urls

I have a website in *Spanish* and *English*.

When there isn't any subdomain selected the preferred language is taken from the browser preferred language or a cookie.

I have the following URLs

```
es.example.com
en.example.com
example.com
```

I want that when an user enter to `es.example.com/any_url` the cookie is set and then is redirected to `example.com/any_url`, but if it's a crawler then is not redirected.

As you can see there isn't any obscure intention here, is just so the URL is cleaner.
Does this have in any kind of penalization by search engines?

Comment: You should red up on [Google's new multi-lingual guidelines](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html)

Comment: Thanks, the 301 is suggested then, with a cookie for the language. I guess the crawlers do take the cookie in account.

Comment: Maybe I should make that an answer then!

Comment: Maybe you should.

Comment: I've gone ahead and done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on [Google's new multi-lingual guidelines](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html).

Comment: And here is [more from Google about multi-lingual](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/09/unifying-content-under-multilingual.html).